# how to get a cross section of a surfplot, created with meshplot and griddata?

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d, mesh, surf

How am i be able to create a 2D cross section of the surfplot?

This is my code:

```
load inp2809moundrederror.txt

x=inp2809moundrederror(:,1);
y=inp2809moundrederror(:,2);
z=inp2809moundrederror(:,3)-1.4;

subplot(2,1,1);
plot3(x,y,z)
axis equal

[XX,YY]=meshgrid(min(x):0.5 :max(x), min(y):0.5:max(y));
[ZZ]=griddata(x,y,z,XX,YY)

subplot(2,1,2);
surf(XX,YY,ZZ)
axis equal
colorbar
```

Part of my .txt file is: [file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SHdoKmbIAJWSLY7f75BI5RLC9CXHuwnjD9qjrPrXlTE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can try it

Comment: And have a look at [`contour3`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour3.html), [`contourc`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourc.html) and [`contourf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html) ... one of them (or a combination) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342244/how-can-i-create-a-slice-of-a-surface-plot-to-create-a-line-matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342244/how-can-i-create-a-slice-of-a-surface-plot-to-create-a-line-matlab)

Comment: @shamalaia Thank you, that is what I needed